# Conceptual Question regarding Partial Differential Equations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider a general equation:
$$ {\partial z\over \partial x }= f(x,y,z)$$

Is it possible to solve this equation like this:
$$ \int d z =\int f(x,y,z) dx $$

Comment: No. The variable $z$ itself depends on $x$, so you cannot evaluate the rightmost integral. This method will work only if $f(x,y,z)=z\cdot g(x,y)$, in which case you can integrate it as a separable ODE in $x$ (and $y$ is just a parameter).

Comment: If you want to solve this equation, look for the "method of characteristics". It is a method more general than the one you have devised and in principle it is going to give you exact solutions. The standard reference for this (AFAIK) is Evans's book on PDEs, fourth chapter.